# Unity: Survival Shooter Tutorial: How to switch between two background songs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am messing around with Unity for an assignment, and I created a "Damage Chain", where if I do damage fast enough, the damage chain increases.

Then, when the damage chain gets high enough, I wanted to switch from the background music to "Enter Sandman" by Metallica...

But when I add the "Enter Sandman" MP3 to the Background music object in the hierarchy, I have to add a second "Audio Source", with the same name (i.e., Audio Source).

Then, when I try to manage it in the code, I can't just run `GetComponent<AudioClip>` like I would anywhere else.

---

How do I toggle between the two songs in a script?  Here is a picture of my object set-up, then the code...

[image]

And, my code (as it is), the SongManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SongManager : MonoBehaviour {
    AudioSource regular_music;
    AudioSource high_dmg_music;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        regular_music = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        high_dmg_music = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();

        regular_music.loop = true;
        regular_music.Play ();

        high_dmg_music.loop = false;
        high_dmg_music.Stop ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (DamageManager.dmg_chain > 1500) {
            regular_music.loop = false;
            high_dmg_music.loop = true;
            high_dmg_music.Play ();
        } else {
            if (high_dmg_music.isPlaying) {
                high_dmg_music.loop = false;
                high_dmg_music.Stop ();
                regular_music.loop = true;
                regular_music.Play ();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Obviously, the code doesn't work, but I finished it anyway.

How would I implement this configuration?

Comment: Just wanted to note how litigious Metallica is. You probably don't want to use that song in a final release.

Comment: Haha, good point; I'm using for an assignment.  I might switch to a different song. I changed the spawn rate to a tenth of a second, made a gigantic gun that shoots 1000 times per second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create only one `AudioSource`. Create many `AudioClips` and then re-assign each `AudioClip` you want to play to the `AudioSource`. Drag the sounds to the `AudioClip` slots.

```
public AudioClip background_music;
public AudioClip sandman_music;

private AudioSource audioSource;

Void Start()
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    //To play backround sound
    if (audioSource.isPlaying)
    {
            audioSource.Stop();
    }
    audioSource.clip = background_music;
    audioSource.Play();

    //To play sandman sound
    if (audioSource.isPlaying)
    {
    audioSource.Stop();
    }
    audioSource.clip = sandman_music;
    audioSource.Play();
}
```

Comment: Ok...so I was dragging to the AudioClip slot in the Audio Source component in the GUI...but it seems to only save one song.  How do I "know about" the AudioClips/retrieve the clips in the script? (very new to this--as in, finished the tutorial yesterday...)

Comment: @bordeo No. Drag the Background Music sound file in your project to the background_music slot and the 45- Enter Sandman file to the sandman_music. That's it.

Comment: Awesome, just figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the clip on audio source.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html

You might want to do it like so(so you can set your music in inspector):

```
    public AudioClip regular_music;
    public AudioClip high_dmg_music;
```

And then just set AudioSource's clip to one of theese.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So I have to somehow add the AudioClip separately?

Comment: No, just drag the songs from your assets into the slots of your script